# How to dynamically change CSS style?

Tags: javascript, css

I have simple element:

```html
<a id="a1" href="#" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; nav-index:1; nav-down:#b1; nav-right:#a3; nav-left:#a1; nav-up:#a1">A1</a>
```

How to dynamically change `nav-index` and `nav-up` only ?

Comment: Is it possible to move those inline styles to a separate style sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**2023**] See this [Stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fnxaro?file=index.js)

Like this:

```
var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
a1.style['nav-index'] = /* somevalue */;
a1.style['nav-up']    = /* somevalue */;
// or (style properties with hypens must be converted
// to a camel case representation for use in 'dot notation')
a1.style.navIndex = /* somevalue */;
a1.style.navUp    = /* somevalue */;
// and to retrieve the original values:
a1.style['nav-index'] = '';
a1.style['nav-up']    = '';
```

Furthermore it's advisable to move the inline styling to a class in a css file.

```
.a1nav {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 nav-index:1;
 nav-down:#b1;
 nav-right:#a3;
 nav-left:#a1;
 nav-up:#a1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('a1').style.navIndex = newIndex;
document.getElementById('a1').style.navUp = newValue;
```

Note that as per [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_nav-up.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_nav-index.asp), `nav-index` and `nav-up` are only supported by Opera.

Answer (score 0):

create a new css and call them using like this

```
function changeClass (elementID, newClass) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);

    element.setAttribute("class", newClass); //For Most Browsers
    element.setAttribute("className", newClass); //For IE; harmless to other browsers.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to change nav-index and nav-up.

```
$('a#a1').attr('nav-index', '2'); //If you want to change it to 2.
$('a#a1').attr('nav-up', '#5'); //If you want to change it to #5.
```